# What is the difference between tel: and sip: uri in SIP?

Tags: sip, voip, sip-server, python-sip

I dint get a clear picture of these two schemes. Can somebody help me to understand.

what i understood is sip uri can contain user agent ip, its name or other identity which can be resolved by sip proxy whereas tel uri contains resolved number and proxy will pass the same as it is to terminating end.

Comment: Or is it like if caller is PSTN then call will go via media gateway. And this gateway will put tell uri in response to callee to inform him that caller is using PSTN network. Its just a guess

Answer (score 0):

A SIP URI consists of a username and host domain name. A SIP URI uniquely identifies a SIP subscriber but does not necessarily resolve to one particular endpoint on a network. For example:

```
sip:john@cisco.com
```

It is also possible to use a directory number as a SIP username and an IP address and port in place of the host domain name. In this case, a SIP URI can uniquely identify an endpoint on a network. For example:

```
sip:1234567@192.167.1.1:5060
```

Local tel URIs may or may not contain a domain name in the phone-context parameter. For example:

```
tel: 1234567;phone-context=cisco.com
```

[Reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/7600/install_config/sbc_config_guide_2/sbc-7600-config-guide/sbc_stl.html#wp1008379).